# Jasmine: Spying on multiple Jquery Selectors that call same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine, bdd

In JavaScript, I have a function I'd like to test using **Jasmine 2.1.3**:

```
   function someFunction(){
     var $firstSelector = $("#firstSelector").val();
     var $secondSelector = $("#secondSelector").val();

     // some function logic
}
```

How can I spy on the **$firstSelector.val()** and **$secondSelector.val()** to provide defined return values for each to test my function? **e.g (i want to spy on $firstSelector.val() to return "Hello" and $secondSelector.val() to return "World")**.

I have read answers that allude to spying on the generic **$.fn** and returning a value for val. But I am unsure how it will give me the control of manually setting return values for different JQuery selector passed in. Is there a concept here I am missing?

Is it possible to have this level of control in terms of mocking JQuery **$(someSelectorVariable).val()** with different selectors as parameters?

Answer (score 1):

So i basically spied on the **$.fn** and used **callFake**. Within the annonymous function i was able to access the **this.selector** property. It was simple from there. I hope this helps anyone!

```
spyOn($.fn, "val").and.callFake(function () {
                switch (this.selector) {
                    case "#firstSelector":
                        return "somethingElse";
                    case "#secondSelector":
                        return "";
                    default:
                        return "";
                }
});
```